# What would be a robust way to install the door stop

Tags: doors, latches

The aluminium door used to have the latch installed on the wall.  And the door used to swing right out to latch to it.

Because the height of the retaining wall was over a metre, we installed this fence.  I need to reinstall the door stop.

- It is laser-cut aluminium panels with a white mesh to enhance the pattern from the other side.
- It is on timber posts.
- The bottom board is only 1 inch thick.
- The panels are not strong enough to take the door stop.
- The hook needs to be about 9" high.

I was thinking of using a 4x4 square tanalised post to lift the hook up.  If the bottom boards had been more substantial, I would have skew nailed it.  I don't see two galvanized brackets on either side of the post being too strong to hold it in place.

Any ideas ?

The Door

[image: Door]

The Hook, it has two holes for screws (one under the black rubber)
[image: Hook]

Comment: Sounds like you're in (or from) a Commonwealth country.  Get yourself a piece of "tanalised" lumber and install it from floor to railing using some pocket screws, paint it white, and mount your latch bracket on it.

Comment: That's not a *doorstop*, although it precluded the need for one (read, don't break the door until you do something). That's a door *holder*. "door holder folding leg". How often do you use it? Just put an actual door stop, and use a brick for that like everyone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

The black band below the panel to the right appears to be wood. If so, just bolt down a piece of pressure treated 4x4 ("tanalised" seems to be British for "pressure treated" in American) to that, then install the catch on that.

Otherwise, drill through the concrete and attach the 4x4 to the step with some appropriate concrete anchors or simple concrete screws (like Tapcon™) and put the catch on that.

In either case, you'll want to be sure the wood is protected from wet/ground contact, or it'll rot out pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Our house has an outward-opening aluminum-and-glass "storm" door like this on the front door. Just like your door, ours has one sided handles (as opposed to door "knobs"). Our door has a pair of door-closer pistons which also limit the door from opening more than about 90 degrees, one at the top and one at the bottom. Did your door not come with door closer pistons?

The two pistons on my door are identical in their door closing function, but the bottom one has a foot actuated button which acts as a door stop allowing the door to be held open in any position from about 85 degrees to 10 deg.

But I wanted to hold the door open at 90 deg for moving bulky items in and out so I mounted a swinging wooden hook on the outside wall which engages the door handle with the flick of a hand. In my case the outside wall is so close to the hinge side of the door that the handle contacts the wall at full extension.

You could mount a rod (wood or aluminum) connected to the wall with a hinge and with a hook on the free end. It would swing out of the way when not being used. The hook would either engage the door handle or the edge of the door and hold the  door open in the 90 or 95 degree open position.